# NullPointer while creating a class with attribute of another class

Tags: java, inheritance, nullpointerexception

I work on a project that stores my **Items** , **Persons** and action when I **Borrow** some **Item** to some **Person**

This project is based on a YouTube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL803F77CA885FC229) for classical library of books.

I'm sorry for I will post some more code because I want to give some idea how I'm doing it. I personally think that there is a problem with how I get the instances of **ItemClass** or **PersonClass**. Or something with inheritance around **BorrowClass**.

Now first two Methods in **BorrowClass** works okay, creating *items* and *persons* and adding to the lists, but when I try to create new **BorrowClass** containing and instance of *items* or *persons* it throws **nullPointer**, yet through debug I was able to see *borrowed* in [variables](http://postimg.org/image/xk2hsquzp/) and everything seemed to be not null or does the red squares means problem ?

I create **ItemClass**

```
public class ItemClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int isbn;
    private String title, author;
    private String otherInfo;

    public ItemClass(String title,String otherInfo, String author,int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.otherInfo = otherInfo;

    }
```

Then **PersonClass**

```
public class PersonClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int telephone;
    private String name, surename, email;

    public PersonClass(String name,String surename, int telephone,String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surename = surename;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.email = email;

    }
```

Then **BorrowCLass**

```
public class BorrowClass implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ItemClass item;
    private PersonClass person;
    private Date borrowDate;
    private Date expireDate;

    public BorrowClass(ItemClass item, PersonClass person, Date borrowDate,
            Date expireDate) {
        this.item = item;
        this.person = person;
        this.borrowDate = borrowDate;
        this.expireDate = expireDate;

    }
```

Now All above I handle in **Library** class

```
public class Library extends Object implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<ItemClass> listOfItems;
    private List<PersonClass> listOfPersons;
    private List<BorrowClass> listOfBorrowed;

    public Library() {
        listOfItems = new ArrayList<ItemClass>();
        listOfPersons = new ArrayList<PersonClass>();
        listOfBorrowed = new ArrayList<BorrowClass>();
    }

    public void addItemtoItemsCollection(ItemClass item) {
        listOfItems.add(item);
    }

    public void addPersontoPersonCollection(PersonClass person) {
        listOfPersons.add(person);
    }

    public void addBorrow(BorrowClass borrowed) {
        listOfBorrowed.add(borrowed);
    }
```

Also would be nice if someone could explain the meaning of

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

because in the video I didn't get it and I would like to know.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: What exactly is the call that throws a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: None of the code you've posted could possibly throw a `NullPointerException`. Please post the line of code that is throwing the `NullPointerException` as indicated in stack trace and you'll likely get a very quick answer here.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. The very first thing to do is to read the stack trace.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it

Comment: The serialVersionUID is used when serializing objects. The compiler will create one for you based on the hash of the class, so it will change every time you change the class. By setting it explicitly, you can serialize without worrying about if the class changes between serialization and de-serialization.

Comment: @RandyKamradtSr. without worrying? Hell no. You'll only get a cryptic error message instead of a clear one.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException        
 at library.model.Library.addBorrow(Library.java:38)       
 at library.controller.LibSystem.AddNewBorrow(LibSystem.java:378)`      This goes to console   on line   `library.addBorrow(borrowed);`

Comment: @Gowronga that doesn't seem possible from the code you are showing us. Did you try to clean your project?

Comment: and I think that earlier I found error like this I think this might be what you asked for `com.sun.jdi.classnotloadedexception: type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array`

Comment: @AndréStannek yes sir I did refresh and clean my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ladies and gentleman I humbly apologise for my stupidity. I have function load from file and I was loading an **OLD** library file where list borrow was still not existing there fore no list to add to. And here I have the nullPointer. I was stuck on this for a while but only for my stupidity :)  Thanks all for help. You can close the topic

Answer (score 0):

About `serialVersionUID` :

So... basically at some point you may want to `serialize` your objects and save them somewhere ( like in a file or in db), so that you can `deserialize` them later. Now, `serialVersionUID` field is used to know, if you are using the same class definition as that was being used when this object was created an serialized.

So... whenever you make a change to some class that is `serializable`, you increase the `serialVersionUID` by 1 so that any `seiralized` object of old class version is not wrongly `deserialized` using the current class version.